# Access 2003 can i query more than 1 table for result

Tags: sql, ms-access

i'm new in access can anyone help how to query more than 1 table for result

ex.

Table   Tdeposit

```
user    amountDeposit
A                5000
A                6000
B                1000
B                3000
```

Table   Twithdraw

```
user    amountWithdraw
A                 2000
A                 3000
B                 1000
```

(Result I need to do)

```
user    current
A          6000 /*edit from 7000* ty for notice*/
B          3000
```

how to i use design view or i need to do in sql view ? thank for help

Comment: please clarify your question, do you want to get the summation of amount for every user

Comment: Search the web for `access query tutorial`.  There are many website and video tutorials.  You'll learn a lot more necessary skills from various tutorials when you're first learning the basics.  Stack Overflow is best suited to asking about specific problems when you can post details about what you have tried so far.  To answer part of your question, you can use the Design View for this task.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 6000 for user A in desired result?

Answer (score 1):

This will work regardless of whether you have rows in any of the tables.

```
    select
    USER, SUM(Amount)
    from
    (
    select 
    user, amountDeposit as Amount from TDeposit
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
    user, -amountWithdraw as Amount from TWithdraw
    ) as x
    Group By user
order by user
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid double counting with multiple instances of same users in each table, consider joining aggregate derived tables, then take difference of sums in outer query:

```
SELECT d.[user], (d.[DepositSum] - w.[WDrawSum]) As [current]
FROM
   (SELECT [user], SUM([amountDeposit]) As DepositSum
    FROM Tdeposit
    GROUP BY [user]) As d
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT [user], SUM([amountWithdraw]) As WDrawSum
    FROM Twithdraw
    GROUP BY [user]) As w
 ON d.[user] = w.[user]
```

Alternatively, you can save each derived table as a separate, saved MS Access query (or view):

```
SELECT d.[user], (d.[DepositSum] - w.[WDrawSum]) As [current]
FROM depositAggQ d
INNER JOIN withdrawAgg w
 ON d.[user] = w.[user]
```

Comment: Assume a user could have deposits and no withdrawals (not the opposite) so don't use INNER join, use a join that returns all records from d and only those from w that match.

Comment: This answer is definitely useful and will lead to the desired results, but notice that the primary question is really 1) "How do I use Design View?" and separately 2) "Do I need to use SQL view?"  This doesn't really answer (1) at all and it's misleading for answering (2) since the first query requires SQL View, but it is not made clear that all 3 of the later queries you mention could all be done in Design View, something very convenient and arguably better for someone new to Access.

Comment: Good point @CPerkins...I will await OP on clarification. Normally SO is not a place for how-to tutorials. Ideally OP would his/her attempt, but I can add how to implement for new Access users.

Comment: Thanks @June7 for point and edit. OP can use `LEFT` in place of `INNER` and convert any nulls to zero with `NZ()` for subtraction expression.

Comment: An aggregate over a UNION is what is required here. I'd post an answer but the combination of tablet and no Access prevents me posting what is the actual answer.

Comment: @LoztInSpace - not quite sure what you mean with `UNION` but this solution outputs the OP's desired, wanted solution. See [SQL Filddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b2e137/1/0). Ignore the use of MS SQL Server dialect to populate tables.

Comment: @Parfait `UNION` explained as an answer.  While your solution works with the data supplied, it will not work if there are no deposits and, as you say, will need some jigging around with outer joins and coalescing if there are no withdrawals.  The problem is classic `UNION` (well actually I'd only have one table, but there might be a reason for having this structure).

Comment: True. However, my solution allows set up of other aggregates like *Count*, *Avg*, *Max*, *Min*, each at the unit levels of deposits and withdraws. +1 nonetheless.